# Issue with Jboss while Isolating the class jar's

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I am trying to isolate my application from jboss class loader.

I have done the settings, in jboss-classloading.xml and jboss-web.xml and drop in my WEBINF folder.

It fixed the issue but starting getting another problem, I keep on searching and could see the solution as isolating the application. Could you please provide solution for this issue..

I am using Jboss 5.1 Enterprise edition.

Could you please let me know what the below issue is creating.

I tried below options.

1. Override xerces jar inside the application lib folder and got this error

Deployment exception.

> **org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException:** Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(SNAPSHOT.ear)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1001)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:437)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:387)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:297)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:61)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
>         at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
>         at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)>
>         at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
>         at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
>         at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>         **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: SNAPSHOT.ear**
>         at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:307)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
>         ... 21 more
>         **Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: SNAPSHOT.war**
>         at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
>         at org.jboss.web.deployers.WARStructure.determineStructure(WARStructure.java:248)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:142)
>         at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.StructureContext.determineChildStructure(StructureContext.java:294)
>         at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.determineStructure(EARStructure.java:277)
>     ... 25 more
>         **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file**
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:636)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:786)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:830)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:195)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:690)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:169)
>         at org.jboss.virtual.plugins
>    2. I tried removing the xerces from application.

Could you please let me know how to identify which jar the application is loading(i tried running the classpath.sh) and which jar is creating the conflict & what is the best way to debug this issue.

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.getConfiguredFactory(ConfigureListener.java:702)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.scanForFacesServlet(ConfigureListener.java:674)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.<init>(ConfigureListener.java:648)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:156)
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossJSFConfigureListener.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
```

**Added jboss-web.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
    <jboss-web>
        <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">                                                     
            <loader-repository>com.example:archive=SNAPSHOT.ear
                <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
            </loader-repository>
        </class-loading>
    <context-root>/contextroot</context-root>

    </jboss-web>
```

Added jboss-classloading.xml

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" 
    name="SNAPSHOT.ear"
    domain="myDomain"
    parent-first="false" 
    parent-domain="DefaultDomain" 
    top-level-classloader="true" 
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="false">
</classloading>
```

Comment: You want to load your application classes using your custom class loader? if yes, then can you provide details about your custom class loader?

Comment: <classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" 
 name="SNAPSHOT.ear"
 domain="myDomain"
 parent-first="false" 
    parent-domain="DefaultDomain" 
    top-level-classloader="true" 
 export-all="NON_EMPTY"
 import-all="false">
</classloading>

Comment: Also added the jboss-web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

can you check this. It was a known issues in JBoss 5.1

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7210

https://community.jboss.org/thread/152151?_sscc=t